# Sorting Nested list in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am doing a problem that my school has assigned to me.
Here is code till now:

```
profits = [1,2,5,6]
weights = [2,3,4,5]
n = 8
ratio = []
count = 0
for i in range(len(profits)):
    ratio.append([])
for i in range(len(ratio)):
    ratio[i].append(weights[i])
    ratio[i].append(profits[i] / weights[i])
```

The output (ratio):

```
[[2, 0.5], [3, 0.6666666666666666], [4, 1.25], [5, 1.2]]
```

But the problem is that I want the list to be sorted maximum ratio wise
like this:

```
[[4, 1.25], [5, 1.2], [3, 0.6666666666666666], [2, 0.5]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a key parameter to `.sort()`.

Below your current code, add:

```py
ratio.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

to sort on the ratio (as opposed to the default sorting mechanism, which starts at the first element in the list).

After this sorting operation, `ratio` will be:

```py
[[2, 0.5], [3, 0.6666666666666666], [5, 1.2], [4, 1.25]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
print(sorted(ratio, key=lambda x: float(x[1]), reverse=True))
```

Output:

```
[[4, 1.25], [5, 1.2], [3, 0.66666666666666663], [2, 0.5]]
```

Comment: I already did it but thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can try sorting by the ratios and then reverse the list

```
def key(e):
# To sort by the 2nd element
  return e[1]

profits = [1,2,5,6]
weights = [2,3,4,5]

ratio =[]
for i in range(len(profits)):
    ratio.append([])
for i in range(len(ratio)):
    ratio[i].append(weights[i])
    ratio[i].append(profits[i] / weights[i])

print(ratio)
ratio.sort(key=key)
ratio = ratio[::-1]
print(ratio)
```

Comment: Why sorting the first element and what does this do: `ratio.sort(key=key)`

Comment: `key` parameter of `sort()` function takes some function(which you can define) as value. sorting will happen based on the return of this function. for example, if you want to sort a bigger 2d list on the basis of its 3rd element
`def key(e):
    return e[2]`
`ratio.sort(key=key)`

Comment: OK. Thanks I get it now.